# Finding specific, easy, closed formula as a tutorial example

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, integers

Is there a sequence in the integer numbers that has the following properties:
a) the sequence has a closed formula without using fractions/devision,
b) the sequence converges,
c) the first m numbers of the sequence contains at least 2 different numbers and m is at least 2.

A friend would like to use this as an example in a tutorial as an easy, non-trivial convergent sequence that does not use fractions/division at all. Is that even possible?

Comment: Are you aware that a sequence of integers is convergent if and only if it is eventually constant?

Comment: yes, i am aware of that. one could argue that you could construct an analogues problem by asking that all numbers from m onward are 0. if you found a convergent sequence you could construct a second sequence with the same closed formula and subtracting the constant to end up with constant zeros.

Comment: What about $a_n = \min(n, m)$?

Comment: is there a closed formula for the minimum function that does not contain fractions?

Comment: Maybe I"m misunderstanding, but it seems to me that when you say "without using division" you mean to allow only addition, subtraction, and multiplication. But that allows only polynomial functions, and all such functions are either constant (failing your requirement of having several different values) or increase to infinity (and so fail to converge).

Comment: $(\cos(2^n\pi))_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ technically works

Comment: @StefanAlbrecht cos technically also uses fractions in its defintion.

Comment: @EdwardMonet that depends on your definition of cosine, I guess. What operations do you allow, exactly? How about $\left((-1)^{2^n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$?

Comment: @MJD i would allow other operations like taking the absolute value too, but i thought about polynomials already too and i agree that polynomials cannot satisfy those conditions.

Comment: I think you need to explain exactly what you consider a closed formula.   For instance, I'd say that a piecewise formula was closed, at least if it had only finitely many cases.

Comment: @StefanAlbrecht i dont really have a list of operations other than "not taking fractions". this was asked in some variations by a student in a tutorial. regarding your sequence: wont that be constantly 1 since 2^n is always even?

Comment: @EdwardMonet No, for $n=0$ we have $(-1)^{2^0}=(-1)^1=-1$. If you want to start the sequence at $n=1$, just jeplace the $n$ with $n-1$.

Comment: @StefanAlbrecht thank you that works too then!

Answer (score 1):

@Martin R you had the right idea. I used [1](https://www.maa.org/programs/faculty-and-departments/classroom-capsules-and-notes/the-maximum-and-minimum-of-two-numbers-using-the-quadratic-formula) to generate a closed formula.

$$f(n) = m + n - |m - n| = 2 * \min(m, n).$$

This always converges to $2m$ after $m$ elements. The first $m-1$ elements are $2*n$ respectively.

@StefanAlbrecht pointed out that the function $f(n) = (-1)^{(2^n)}$ satisfies the criteria too with $f(0) = -1$ and $f(n) = 1$ for all $n > 0$.